# Maintaining list of connected websocket clients in java

Tags: java, android, websocket, client-server

I am developing a simple chat application between **Android client and java server**. I am using **websocket for communication**.

Can we maintain the connected clients sessions in a hashmap and send messages to the respective client whenever any new message arrives?
How long is the session valid?

I have googled but I didn't get much info.

Comment: @flob Thanks for the edit. I couldn't check it till now. else I would have edited once I observed ur edit suggestion.

Comment: What implementation are you using server-side? Tyrus? Otherwise, the main idea is that this is doable thanks to a `SessionHandler` class which encapsulates all existing connections. However, it is sensitive to clustering and all the replication stuff

Comment: No I am using plain Java. However I am figuring out all other frameworks . Netty is out of case for me as netty don't support Android. Other option for me is Jetty . Jetty has support for both Java and android I believe. Could you please suggest any better frameworks.

Comment: Plain Java EE or plain Java SE? If you're using Java SE as a "server", I'm not sure if it can handle websocket without adding a third party framework. If you're using Java EE, the JSR 356 is the specification for websocket and Tyrus is the standard implementation of it.